# Выражение должно иметь тип указателя или дескриптора

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

Пишу класс однонаправленного списка при помощи шаблонов. Метод TList::Print() мне необходимо переписывать для каждого типа отдельно.

Код:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node* next;
};


template <typename T>
class TList
{
public:
    TList();
    ~TList();

    void Add( T data );
    T* GetI(unsigned int i);
    void DeleteElement(Node<T>* el, unsigned int n);

    void Print();

private:
    
    Node<T>* Head;

};
```

Для случая когда у меня элементом списка является экземпляр класса Ttarget:

```
void TList<TTarget>::Print()
{
    Node<TTarget>* tmp = Head;
    while (tmp != nullptr)
    {
        cout << "X: " <<  tmp->data->state_vector[0] << " Y: " << tmp->data->state_vector[1] << endl;
        //,,,,,,,,,,
    }
    return;
}
```

В выражении `tmp->data->state_vector[0]` требуется тип указателя и дескриптора. Что я должен написать, если `tmp` имеет тип `Node<TTarget>*` , `tmp->data` имеет `TTarget*`, `state_vector` имеет `double*`?

Comment: а разве разумно в список добавлять метод `print`? Если вы считаете что "да", то что делать с данными, которые нельзя вывести с помощью `cout` - например какой-нибудь ваш кастомный класс, для которого не определен `operator<<`?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Согласен. Тогда пусть у меня mp->data имеет TTarget* , а Ttarget содержит метод Print().  Строка tmp->data->Print(); выдает ту же ошибку: Выражение должно иметь тип указателя или дескриптора

Comment: так а какой тип у вашего `tmp->data`?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Это ссылка на класс TTarget

Comment: раз ссылка, то почему вы обращаетесь к методу через `->`? Вас ничего не смущает?

Comment: Если честно, то всегда считал, что если ссылка, то -> если просто тип данных, то . Спасибо

Comment: вам стоит подучить азы